# use ajax to upload file in Django

Tags: python, django

I am going to add a button in my page to upload file.User clicks this button and choose file from computer, the page will upload file to the server and show a message like 'Upload successfully' to the user.

I have noticed that Django has `Filefield` in model and we can define a `class FileForm` so that we can use `form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` and `form.save()` to upload.

However,as I want to refresh part of the page after upload, it comes to me to use ajax to send data.Furthermore,in order to use `request.FILES` which requires that request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data", I think maybe we can use `FormData()` in ajax.

html:

```
<div>
<input type="file" name="" id="ul_input">
<input type="hidden" name="local_id" id="get-local-id" value="{{ record.local_id }}"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// grab your file object from a file input
$('#ul_input').change(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("ul_file", this.files[0]);
    formData.append("filename", this.files[0].name);
    formData.append("local_id", $('#get-local-id').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadfile',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log("loading...please wait");
        },
        success: function (responseStr) {
            if (responseStr.status === 0) {
                alert('upload successfully');
            } else {
                alert("upload fail");
            }
        },
        error: function (responseStr) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def order_upload(request):  
    status = 1
    if request.is_ajax():
        local_id = request.POST.get('local_id')
        post = DetailList.objects.get(local_id=local_id)
        post.order_dir = request.FILES['ul_file']
        post.save()
        status = 0
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': status}), content_type='application/json')
```

models.py

```
def file_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'file_list/{0}{1}/{2}'.format(instance.upload_date.strftime('%Y'),
                                          instance.upload_date.strftime('%m'),
                                          filename)

class DetailList(models.Model):
    local_id = models.IntegerField(...)
    start_date = models.DateField(...)
    order_dir = models.FileField(upload_to=file_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

Dont forget to set `MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'` in settings.py

I try to upload a file 'test.docx'.Now it seems that I have alreay uploaded file to `media/file_list/201807/test.docx`.I also check `order_dir`in table,it has already become `file_list/201807/test.docx`.And I got the alert says 'upload successfully'.

However,I can't find my 'test.docx' in directory 'media/file_list/201807/test.docx'.

Where is the file I uploaded? Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try to set `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: I tried.it doesn't work.

Comment: finally I figured out.it should be MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')